# Matrix of the linear transformation $T$

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, polynomials, linear-transformations

To the following theorem,

> Let $V$ and $W$ be finite-dimensional vector spaces having ordered bases $\beta$ and $\gamma$, respectively, and let $T : V \rightarrow W$ be linear. Then, for each $u \in V$, we have $[T(u)]_\gamma=[T]_\beta^\gamma[u]_\beta$.

the textbook gives the following example:

Let $T:P_3(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow P_2(\mathbb{R})$ be the linear transformation defined by $T(f(x))=f'(x)$, and let $\beta$ and $\gamma$ be the standard ordered bases for $P_3(\mathbb{R})$ and $P_2(\mathbb{R})$, respectively. If $A=[T]_\beta^\gamma$, then we have
$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now, the textbook tries to illustrate the previous theorem by verifying that $[T(p(x))]_\gamma=[T]_\beta^\gamma[p(x)]_\beta$, where $p(x)\in P_3(\mathbb{R})$ is the polynomial $p(x)=2-4x+x^2+3x^3$. Then, it takes $q(x)=T(p(x))$ and $q(x)=p'(x)=-4+2x+9x^2$ and he gets that $$[T(p(x))]_\gamma=[q(x)]_\gamma=
\begin{bmatrix}
-4\\
2\\
9\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The thing that I really don't understand is why does it take $q(x)=p'(x)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard basis of $P_{3}(\mathbb{R})$ is $1, x, x^{2}, x^{3}$. The example shown is the polynomial $p(x) = 2 -4x + x^2 + 3x^3$. The coordinates of $p$ with respect to the standard basis are thus
$$ [p(x)]_{\beta} =  \begin{pmatrix}
           2 \\
           -4 \\
           1 \\
           3
\end{pmatrix}.$$

If we now apply the linear transformation $T$ to $p$, we get the polynomial $q(x) = T(p(x)) = -4 + 2x + 9x^{2} $ in $P_{2}(\mathbb{R})$. Now with respect to the standard basis of $P_{2}(\mathbb{R})$, the coordinates of $T(p(x))$ are

$$ [T(p(x))]_{\gamma} =  \begin{pmatrix}
           -4 \\
           2 \\
           9 
\end{pmatrix}.$$
If you do the calculations, $[T(p(x))]_{\gamma}$ can also be obtained as

$$ [T]_{\beta}^{\gamma} [p(x)]_{\beta} =  \begin{pmatrix}
           0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
           0 & 0 & 2 & 0\\
           0 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
           2 \\
           -4 \\
           1 \\
           3
\end{pmatrix} = 2 \begin{pmatrix}
           0 \\
           0 \\
           0 
\end{pmatrix} -4 \begin{pmatrix}
           1 \\
           0 \\
           0 
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}
           0 \\
           2 \\
           0 
\end{pmatrix} + 3 \begin{pmatrix}
           0 \\
           0 \\
           3 
\end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix}
           -4 \\
           2 \\
           9 
\end{pmatrix}. $$

The theorem quoted implies that we can recover the coordinates of $q(x) = T(p(x))$ for any polynomial $p$ in $P_{3}(\mathbb{R})$ via matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

Because$$q(x)=T\bigl(p(x)\bigr)=p'(x),$$by the definition of $T$.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you are asking:

### Why can you assert $q(x) = p'(x)$?

Well, the book defines $T(f(x)) = f'(x)$. Now, we can apply this definition to $p(x)$:

$$T(p(x)) = p'(x)$$

Since the book defines $q(x) = T(p(x))$, we get

$$q(x) = T(p(x)) = p'(x)$$

So $$q(x) = p'(x)$$